# SKSpriteNode has given itself teleporting capabilities and it can't be stopped

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

If anyone has ever played league of legends, they know that you click an area to make a player move to that spot. They don't get there instantly, it takes a little bit of time. I've tried to add this functionality to a game that I am trying to make. The problem is, the character tends to sometimes move slowly towards the touched area, which is great because that is what I want, but some times there is an inconsistency where it teleports instantaneously to the touched spot. Can anyone see the problem?

```
let touch                   = touches.anyObject()! as UITouch
let location                = touch.locationInNode(self)
let moveAction              = SKAction.moveTo(location, duration: 3.0)              

if(tankTurn)    // Tank's turn when tankTurn is true.
{
    tank.runAction(moveAction)

    tank.position               = location
    tankTurn                    = false
}// if statement
```

Comment: Deleting the `tank.position = location` statement should fix the problem

Comment: Completely did the trick, thank you very much.

Comment: BTW, you should change the duration of SKAction.moveTo based off the distance between location and the tank's position. That way it'll be a bit smarter.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that last night. Changed and it looks a little bit better, thanks.